# Partial differentiation of a tensor

Tags: tensors

I'm currently struggling with an optimization problem. My objective is to find the rotation $X$ that minimize the $l_1$ norm of $Q_{ijk}$ defined as:

$\tilde{Q}_{ijk} = \sum_{p,q,r = 1}^{N} X_{pi}Q_{pqr}X_{qj}X_{rk}$

Thus the objective function is : $|| \tilde{Q}_{ijk}||_1 $

So far I managed to evaluate numerically the gradient of the objective function with respect $X$. Since this operation is quite costly and does not allow to scale the algorithm to larger problems I was wondering how to find an analytical expression of the gradient of the $l_1$ norm of $\tilde{Q}$ with respect $X$.

Many thanks for any help!

Riccardo

Comment: Does it seem a problem of mathematics rather than that of Mathematica?

Comment: I posted here since I was trying to use Mathematica to compute the derivative and I'd have liked to know if someone else faced similar problems

Comment: Th objective function is not differentiable.

Comment: But you can do anyway gradient descend...

Comment: I was actually hoping to find an efficient way to compute the derivative of $\tilde{Q}_{ijk}$ with respect the rotation matrix $X$. Once those are know it is possible to perform gradient descent.